# Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Marketing cloud FuelSDK)

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, ssl, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Since, yesterday I am getting `SSL error` when trying to access **Marketing cloud APIs** using [FuelSDK-Ruby](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Ruby).

It keep on throwing the two errors `SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A` and `Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect`.

I am using **OpenSSL version: 1.0.2l (macOS Sierra version: 10.12)**

**Below is the trace of the errors:**

```
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:36:in `rescue in request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:27:in `request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi.rb:137:in `request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi.rb:103:in `get'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:42:in `load_from_remote'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:32:in `resolve'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:120:in `xml'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:138:in `parse'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:125:in `parser'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:61:in `soap_actions'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:21:in `ensure_exists!'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:14:in `create'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:32:in `operation'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/soap.rb:275:in `soap_request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/soap.rb:219:in `soap_get'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/objects.rb:43:in `get'
```

---

```
Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
/Users/gokul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:54:in `do_request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:31:in `request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi.rb:137:in `request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/httpi-2.0.2/lib/httpi.rb:103:in `get'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:42:in `load_from_remote'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/resolver.rb:32:in `resolve'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:120:in `xml'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:138:in `parse'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:125:in `parser'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/wasabi-3.1.0/lib/wasabi/document.rb:61:in `soap_actions'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:21:in `ensure_exists!'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:14:in `create'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:32:in `operation'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/soap.rb:275:in `soap_request'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/soap.rb:219:in `soap_get'
/Users/gokul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@mcapp/bundler/gems/FuelSDK-Ruby-384a48ab965a/lib/marketingcloudsdk/objects.rb:43:in `get'
```

Can anyone help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with other network and it is working fine.

The issue is because of my network & firewall setting, blacklisting, etc.. I don't know exactly what behind this issue and it is working fine with other network.